# VanillaJS: grab the text from multiple elements (same class) and list in separate div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the text content of a specific class across the page, then print them out in a different div, separated by a comma.

Example:

```
<!-- Within the HTML Page -->
<div class="copyright">Image one</div>
<div class="copyright">Image two</div>
<div class="copyright">Image three</div>

<!-- Should output: "Image one, Image two, Image three" -->
<div class="showCopyright"></div>
```

How would I achieve this using only pure VanillaJS, not jQuery?

Would I use the innerHTML? or innerText?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use textContent unless there is or you want markup in the result

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { 

  document.querySelector(".showCopyright")
    .textContent = [...document.querySelectorAll(".copyright")]
      .map(({ textContent }) => textContent.trim()).join(", ");

});
```

```html
<!-- Within the HTML Page -->
<div class="copyright">Image one</div>
<div class="copyright">Image two</div>
<div class="copyright">Image three</div>

<!-- Should output: "Image one, Image two, Image three" -->
<div class="showCopyright"></div>
```

Comment: great, running the code snippet works, however, where I want to apply the script I get an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')" - any idea what might cause it?

Comment: most likely because you load the script before them `DOMContent` is loaded. add a `defer` attribute to the script tag or an `eventListener` for `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: Yes, I packed it inside DOMContentLoaded and works now :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure javascript method to do that:

```js
var textArray = [];
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("copyright");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   textArray.push(elements[i].innerText);
}
    
document.getElementsByClassName("showCopyright")[0].innerText = textArray.join(', ');
```

```html
<div class="copyright">Image one</div>
<div class="copyright">Image two</div>
<div class="copyright">Image three</div>
<div class="showCopyright"></div>
```

Comment: This will always have a trailing comma. You should push to an array instead and join at the end. Also see [my answer] for a more modern version

Comment: as an addition to what mpluging already said, your method is too long and misses simplicity. If you want to go with your method then write the string in backticks: `text += '${elements[i].innerText},'` (just replace the single quotes with backticks!)